# Adding user registration to IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer template `is4aspid`, which comes with asp.net identity, I would like to add a register page to it. I don't want to do it on my main MVC app as I don't want it to have access to the users DB, and hence the identityServer already has that reference, I thought it would be better to just add the registration step to it.

I copied the Register.cshtml page from another asp.net webapplication, where I scafolded the identity, but when I click on register, nothing happens, not sure what is happening

[image].

As you can see in the picture above, after clicking on the Register link, the url changes to the one supposed to provide the registration form, but the page remains the same of the login form.

I added the following line to _Layout.cshtml

[image]

Comment: You were correct on putting registration on the IS project, as it's the only one that should have user db access. Have you added Register method into the account controller and created models for it?

Comment: I managed to get it to work, partially. I will come back here and post an answer on how did I do it, as there are few changes

Comment: That URL means that you need to be authenticated to access the Register page. Simply use the `[AllowAnonymous]` Attribute.